# what is the most efficient way to get multiple columns from multiple tables in oracle?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I'm dealing with up to a billion records in oracle and I really need efficiency.
The first table is `notification`. I need to obtain the following data.

```
src_data_id | match_data_id
```

The second table is `person_info`. id is same as src_data_id and match_data_id from the `notification` table.

```
id | name
```

The third table is `sample_info`, in which self_object_id is the foreign key for `person_info`.

```
id | self_object_id
```

The forth table is `sample_dna_gene` where sample_id is same as id in `sample_id`.

```
sample_id | gene_info
```

I am writing a program in Java and I want to encalsulate a list of objects. Each object contains the name (from person_info) and gene_info (from gene_info).

Originally, I did it in 2 steps. I joined notification and person_info to obtain the ids. Then I joined person_info, sample_info and gene_info to obtain the names and their corresponding gene_info.

This would be fine for a smaller database, but dealing with up to a billion records, I need to worry about speed. I should not join the three tables like I did, but use simple sqls for each table, and join the pieces in Java instead.

It was easy to get ids from person_info with separate sqls, but I'm having trouble with obtaining their corresponding `gene_info`. I can get sample_info.id with a simple sql using in(id1,id2,id3...). I can then find gene_info with another simple sql using in(id1,id2,id3...).

I can obtain all these lists in java, but how do I put them together? I'm using spring and mybatis. Originally I could make one big messy sql and encapsulates all elements in the mapper. I'm not sure what to do now.

edit: The messy sql I have right now is

```
select to_char(sdg.gene_info), max(aa.pid), max(aa.sid), max(aa.id_card_no)
  from (select max(pi.person_name),
           max(pi.id) pid,
           si.id sid,
           max(pi.id_card_no),
           max(pi.race)
      from person_info pi
      join sample_info si
        on pi.id = si.self_object_id
     group by si.id) aa
  join sample_dna_gene sdg
    on sdg.sample_id = aa.sid
 group by to_char(sdg.gene_info)
 where aa.pid in ('...')
```

It's a little more complicated than the orginal question. I need to group by id in sample_id first, then group by gene_info in sample_data_gene. I had to use a lot of max() so group by would work, and even then, I still could not get the gene_info group by to work properly. I'm not sure how ineffcient the max() is and how much it will slow down the query, but you can clearly see the point why I wanted to avoid such a messy sql now.

Comment: If anything needs clarified, please ask away.

Comment: I think the simpler question is... how do pull data from multiple tables together without joining them in sql, but wrap them together in java instead.

Comment: Why do you think joining data in a relational database (which is, of course, all about joining tables efficiently!) will be slower than joining the data separately in Java? You'll be pulling across more data that way plus the work of storing the data to process it, etc. I am assuming that your tables have got up-to-date statistics gathered against them (including histograms if your data is skewed) plus any necessary indexes. It would help if you could edit your question to add your current joined query.

Comment: If you have a billion row database which has been modelled and implemented by someone experienced in wrangling billion row tables then SQL joins are going to be the most efficient way of retrieving data. So, we have to ask you, have you actually written a query which joins all four tables, and for which you get sub-optimal response times? Or is this just premature optimisation?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have included the sql in my question now. I'm doing this with a much smaller database of only a few hundred records, so I have not actually tested the speed, but I just assumed this sql would cause problems with the actual enormous database.

Comment: Do not assume: probe and verify.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case. It was delt with 4 separate readers one for each table and merging was done on java side. Unfortunately prerequisite for that was sorting income streams on database side. 
You read single record from stream one then you read records from stream 2 until key changes (as you sorted by that key and key is common for all tabs) then same for following streams. In my case that made sense as first table was very wide and next 3 had many rows for single key in table 1. If in your case there are no 1:n (where n is big) relations I don't see why such approach can be better than join.